# Remove Security.salt and Security.cipherSeed value Admin login not working

Tags: cakephp-2.2

If i Remove Security.salt and Security.cipherSeed value then Admin login not working.

```
Configure::write('Security.salt', '');
Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', '');
```

Please Help

Comment: Why the hell would you erase that? This is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the Admin login will not work. The AuthComponent needs that Strings to `hash` the  User Data in the Session, as well for persisting passwords on the database.

Since you already have the passwords hashed on your databese, when you submit the admin login form, it will hash the password you just sent via input and compare with the database one to see if they match, if they do, permission is granted.

Considering that you deleted the salt, the hash will now have a different behavior compared to one with a provided salt, thus, it will output different hashes for the same input, which means permission is denied and will remain like this until you come back to the exact same `salt`.

When you bake a project with the `cake bake` command, it will generate and replace the default salts for you.
Remember, when you change this salts, every single password stored in the database will need to be rehashed, then you need to provide your users a way to do this, like a 'forgot my password' mechanism.

---

**NOTE:** [**This**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html#optional-configuration) might appear as a optional step, but it is more like a "**Must do" Configuration**, and it should be done just after install. Remember that using an wide know Salt is a HUGE security flaw.